# Using proxy_pass, can I redirect or proxy */ to */index.html

Tags: nginx

I have a website hosted on `my.web.server`. The files are hosted on `file.host/myfiles`. I am using Nginx to proxy the domain to the file host.

The config file reads as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.web.server;

    location ^~ /cdn {      
        proxy_pass https://file.host/myfiles;
    }
}
```

This successfully proxies all requests coming in to the destination file host, however I get no redirects to `index.html` should a `/` or  route be entered.

An example of what I'd like to achieve is here:

```
my.web.server/cdn           => my.web.server/cdn/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/          => my.web.server/cdn/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/images    => my.web.server/cdn/images/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/images/   => my.web.server/cdn/images/index.html

my.web.server/cdn/**/       => my.web.server/cdn/**/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/**        => my.web.server/cdn/**/index.html
```

Ideally, you wouldn't see the `index.html` in the URL and it would simply proxy to that file path, however if that's not possible, redirecting the user there would also be fine.